# Looping rows in html table with php

Tags: php

I want to write the rows as many as the number stated in `$row`. (instead of one row only). How can I achieve this? What am I doing wrong? thanks.

```
<?php
   $row = 50;  
   echo "<table border='1'>";
   for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++)
     echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>L1</td><td>L2</td><td>L3</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
  echo $i+1;
    }
?>
```

Comment: For starters your closing table tag in inside your loop

Comment: You missed an open bracket { just after  for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++) and you don't need $i+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing table inside the loop. Change to the following

```
    <?php
       $row = 50;  
       echo "<table border='1'>";
       for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++){
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>L1</td><td>L2</td><td>L3</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
       }
       echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on line 9. when i run this code.

Comment: @Max try now. Opening braces for `for loop` was missing

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.

Comment: I will accept, but I have to wait 7 minutes now. the site doesn't allow the answer to be accepted right away.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
       $row = 50;  
       echo "<table border='1'>";
       for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++)
       {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>L1</td><td>L2</td><td>L3</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
       }
       echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code i have added some mistake done by you

```
<?php
$row = 50;  
echo "<table border='1'>";
for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++){ //add bracket here
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>L1</td><td>L2</td><td>L3</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    //echo $i+1; //remove this one
}
echo "</table>"; //close table tag outside the loop
?>
```